# It does not show me the requested page

Tags: javascript

I have this problem, when the user is validated I ask the server for the following page but it does not show it. I do not have experience.
Thank you.

```
let base_url = window.location.origin;
function Login() {
    let url = base_url + "/login";
    let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url + "?username="+ username + "&password=" + password, false);
    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status == 200) {  
        xhr.open("GET", base_url + "/getacdreport", false);
        xhr.send();
        //console.log(xhr.responseText); 
    } else {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ? I mean, inside your `if` block, redirecting to another `URL` ?

```
if (xhr.status == 200) {  
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/getacdreport";
    //console.log(xhr.responseText); 
} else {
    alert("Invalid username/password");
}
```

Comment: yes, If the login is correct, I want you to send me the main page

Comment: One question, if login fail, how can i show the fail message in the login page?

Comment: i have edited the post, just add an `else` block - inside that i have added `alert` line, but you can add  logic - like setting text of any `div` to `invalid username/password` instead of `alert`

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba.